# Solve this triangle as AREA?

Tags: geometry

[image]

Can somebody calculate the area of this triangle?

Comment: Hint: it's a trick question (sort of).  Try drawing a more accurate scale diagram of the triangle.

Comment: +1 to David, this is not a triangle as 2+3=5. Area calculation is N/A

Answer (score 2):

Did anyone notice that $2+3=5$? What does the triangle inequality say?

Comment: No it's not a right traingle. Don't be confused, the Pythagorean theorem says $a^2+b^2=c^2$, while here we don't have squares. In our case the two sides sum up to the third, which means that it's just a straight line! (area=$0$)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use [Hero(n)'s formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula). Let a triangle have sides of length $a,b,c$. Define the semiperimeter $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$. Then, the area of the triangle is $\sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)}$.

Comment: This is the general, heavy-weight solution. But take a good look to the *triangle*, as David points out.

Comment: Indeed. I just put this as a solution after David's comment since its a handy thing to know in general, given its usually less annoying than dropping a perpendicular and then calculating out the stuff for two triangles.

Comment: @IhechukwuChinyere What do you expect for such a triangle. Draw a scaled diagram.

Answer (score 1):

As we can see the sides of given triangle doesn’t satisfy triangle inequality ( sum of any two sides of a triangle greater than the third side).

The given geometry is not a triangle but $A, B, C$ are the points on a straight line as $5 = 2 + 3 $

So the area of given figure is  **$0$**